# Spring templates: how to execute multiple SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

I want to execute some SQL code (on MySQL) that looks like this (it's not a stored procedure):

```
START TRANSACTION;  

INSERT...;
SELECT...;

COMMIT;
```

How can I do it using Spring templates?
When I try to use JdbcTemplate, it seems like Spring does not understand the query.

Is not allowed to start the transaction from the SQL code, when using Spring templates?

When using Spring templates, can I start a transaction from the SQL code, when using stored procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Spring `TransactionTemplate`, it's the best way to do transactions while using the JDBC template (see here the [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s06.html)):

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

  protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {

      jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?)",
         new Object[] { firstName, lastName });

     ... multiple calls to JDBC template, all inside the same transaction ....
  }
});
```